# How to flush stdin without requiring user input?

Tags: c, stdin, flush

I'm trying to simulate a command line shell. The user inputs a shell command they want to input, e.g. `/bin/pwd` and the code is meant to execute it.

The buffer is set to read a fixed number of chars (let's say 20 for example).

In the case that the user inputs more than 20 chars, the excess characters need to be flushed before the shell loops again.

I've been trying to do this like so:

```
int garbageCollector; 
while ((garbageCollector = getchar()) != '\n' && garbageCollector != EOF);
```

But the problem is `getChar()` requires you to input a char first.

Is there a way to flush stdin that doesn't require user to input anything?

```
while (1) {

    // Prompt user for input
    ssize_t readIn = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUF_SIZE + 1);
    if (readIn < 0) {
        perror("read() failed");
        return 2;
    } 

    // Null-terminate and remove line return
    buffer[readIn - 1] = '\0'; 

    char program[strlen(buffer)];
    strcpy(program, buffer);
    printf("program is: %s\n", program);

    // Flush stdin
    int garbageCollector; 
    while ((garbageCollector = getchar()) != '\n' && garbageCollector != EOF);

    // Create child process
    child = fork();
    if (child < 0) {
        perror("fork() failed");
        return 3;
    }

    // Start alarm that is triggered after timeout exceeded
    // which then kills child process
    signal(SIGALRM, killChild);
    alarm(timeout); 

    if (child == 0) { // Child
        char* av[] = { program, NULL };
        execve(program, av, NULL);  

    } else {  // Parent
        wait(NULL);
        alarm(0);  // Reset alarm if program executed
    }

    memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE); // Flush buffer
}
```

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: Note that 20-character command lines are not viable in the medium term — it is just too excruciatingly short.  2000 characters and maybe you'd be in the running.

Comment: Shells like Bash put the terminal into a non-canonical mode and read using that — not using the standard I/O functions.  It's more akin to using the Curses library.

Comment: Yes the 20 char was just an example. How can I flush the buffer without standard I/O functions?

Answer (score 2):

If non-POSIX portability is not a concern (note that this will not work with Windows - but I see you're using fork() which also will not work with Windows), you could temporarily make the file descriptor you're attempting to flush non-blocking and read all input from it:

```
int flush_in(FILE *file)
{
    int ch;
    int flags;
    int fd;

    fd = fileno(file);
    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK)) {
        return -1;
    }
    do {
        ch = fgetc(file);
    } while (ch != EOF);
    clearerr(file);
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then you would call `flush_in(stdin)`.

Answer (score 1):

Someone in a related question suggested this:

```
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
```

Seems to work on Mac and Windows but not Linux. For Linux, Daniel's suggestion works:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

So, you can solve this at compile time and use either `fflush` or `fseek` depending on the OS you're compiling for.

```
#ifdef defined(_WIN32) || defined(__APPLE__)
  #define flush_stdin(stdin) fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END)
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__unix__)
  #define flush_stdin(stdin) fflush(stdin)
#else
  #define flush_stdin(...) UNIMPLEMENTED
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a quick aside- if I were to use only system calls, ie no library functions like fflush and fseek, then how could I implement this?

Comment: @doctopus I up voted craig's solution because it is better, and it will work on *nix / osx. If you need to do this on windows, use [fflush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=vs-2017#example), which does exactly what you want even if you pass `stdin`. `fflush` is apparently UB on *nix/osx but fairly widely implemented.

Comment: @doctopus Although, I see nothing wrong with my note at the bottom. Calling read until EOF will work anywhere.

Comment: when I implement your code at the bottom, it makes me go into an infinite loop where it keeps prompting for user input @okovko

Comment: @doctopus Never mind, I don't know what I was thinking. Need some sleep. :P

Comment: heh. any idea how i could implement this without use of library functions then? it's driving me a little crazy

Comment: @doctopus See Jonathan Leffler's comments.